# Swift: Is it possible to remove View Controller from stack?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I found a Github repository where the user has created a launch animation like in twitters app: [This](https://github.com/okmr-d/App-Launching-like-Twitter)

This works best if the icon is a solid shape and being centered in the screen.

My problem is that I can center my icon because how its designed. So when my animation is finished the app will still have some masking left on the screen from the previously View Controller that made the animation.

So is it possible to remove that View Controller completely once the animation is done and the app hits the table view View Controller?

Here is my code:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 196/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        // rootViewController from StoryBoard
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigationController") as! UIViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController

        // logo mask
        navigationController.view.layer.mask = CALayer()
        navigationController.view.layer.mask.contents = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!.CGImage
        navigationController.view.layer.mask.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
        navigationController.view.layer.mask.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        navigationController.view.layer.mask.position = CGPoint(x: navigationController.view.frame.width / 2, y: navigationController.view.frame.height / 2)

        // logo mask background view
        var maskBgView = UIView(frame: navigationController.view.frame)
        maskBgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navigationController.view.addSubview(maskBgView)
        navigationController.view.bringSubviewToFront(maskBgView)

        // logo mask animation
        let transformAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
        transformAnimation.delegate = self
        transformAnimation.duration = 1
        transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1 //add delay of 1 second
        let initalBounds = NSValue(CGRect: navigationController.view.layer.mask.bounds)
        let secondBounds = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        let finalBounds = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000))
        transformAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
        transformAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
        transformAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)]
        transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
        transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        navigationController.view.layer.mask.addAnimation(transformAnimation, forKey: "maskAnimation")

        // logo mask background view animation
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1,
            delay: 1.35,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn,
            animations: {
                maskBgView.alpha = 0.0
            },
            completion: { finished in
                maskBgView.removeFromSuperview()
        })

        // root view animation
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,
            delay: 1.3,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone,
            animations: {
                self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05)
            },
            completion: { finished in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
                    delay: 0.0,
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
                    animations: {
                        self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    },
                    completion: nil
                )
        })
```

And the problem is worse on iPad where the screen is bigger = more masking left on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the mask after the animation is done.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,
        delay: 1.3,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone,
        animations: {
            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
                delay: 0.0,
                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
                animations: {
                    self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                },
                completion: { 
                     // ADDED THIS LINE
                     self.window!.rootViewController!.view.layer.mask = nil
                }
            )
    })
```

Comment: Using that I get an error: cannot invoke animateWithDuration with an argument list of type: (Double, delay:Double,options:UIViewAnimationOptions,animations: () -> _,completion: (_) -> _)